# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header vs cross domain policy

Tags: asp.net, iis, cross-domain, cors

So I'm reading up on these and am a little confused.  I'm using an iframe of a site on another domain.  I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.”  Reading up on this I can just set the header in the web.config.  However, I want multiple specific domains and not just the wildcard "*".  I was reading up on the cross domain policy.  Creating an xml file  Is this by any means related or are these two completely different things?

This xml policy

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="domain1.com"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="domain2.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

vs this in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>    
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="site1.com" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS works by adding a special header to responses from a server to the client. If a response contains the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, and if the browser supports CORS, then there is a chance you can load the resource directly with Ajax no need for a proxy.

> When you set, Access-Control-Allow-Origin value as “site1.com”.

With this configuration, only scripts that originate from http://site1.com are allowed to load resources. Any other domain trying to use Ajax to load resources will be given the standard security error message. In this way, site owners can limit which domains are allowed to load their resources with CORS.

Alternatively, site owners can grant wide-open access with the always ready to party asterisk:

> **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ***.

Now, any site that wants to load a resource directly using Ajax can do so without getting the browser security error. It's a very helpful technique for modern apps that often load data using JavaScript, and hopefully more modern web APIs will start to support CORS.